# error: 80040154 Class not registered - WPF

Tags: visual-studio, dll, 32bit-64bit

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class
> factory for component with CLSID
> {9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

I'm running the code on a X64 machine with "Any CPU".
I tried to change from "Any CPU" to "x84" and to "x64" and I still get the same error.